# Simple private messaging system. How to mark as read

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm building an app in Laravel, and using the eloquent ORM.

i want to create a simple private messaging system within my application. Nothing mad complex. It will basicaly  be like email. It has a recepient, title, content and timestamps.

I want the ability  to show if it's read/unread. Would having a column as a boolean called 'read' which has a default value of 0 work. When the user clicks on it, the read attirbute changes to 1, and the message is marked as read.

How would I update the attribute, when the message is opened.

Comment: Could you share some of the code you have tried so far? we'll need something to build our answers upon

Comment: The answer is simply: change the status when the user views the message using query builder or your eloquent model.

Comment: your idea sounds good, but to help you we need to see an actual implementation :)

Comment: I don't mean to be disrespectful, but by literally googling the keywords of your post (update attribute laravel), I found tons of tutorials that explain what you want to do. Not in the least, the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#updates

Comment: I don't have an actual imlementation yet. I'm preparing to build it at the moment. I'll get back here, if i'm struggling and post some code. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

*Laravelish* way, is to use a column named `read_at`, and set it to `NULL` if unread, and the current timestamp when read.

Migration part of `read_at` may look like:

```
$table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable()->default(null);
```

> **Note**: do not forget to add `read_at` to [`$dates` array](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) so working with `read_at` is easy - carbon way.

Comment: With this solution you get to know **if** as well as **when** message was read.

Comment: I agree with this one. As far as implementation: when the user is being redirected to the page to read the message, you may use something like `$message->update('read_at', Carbon::now());` before continuing on with returning the next view.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using front-end framework like Angular or react, make ajax request to your controller function. In controller function update the db table using ORM or Query Builder. Using Ajax you can do it without affecting to the user view.

Comment: While ajax is amazing, that is one extra request. If the person is already going to be redirected to the new page to read it, the value could be updated in that controller.

Answer (score 0):

if you are making simple messaging system, store a flag with `read`. When the user clicks on a message, take that message's id and update that records `read` with 1 and unread 0 using an update action.

Comment: Why would you use 2 columns for one boolean, message is either **read** or **not read**.. so use only one column.